# JavaFX Rectangles inside FlowPane

Tags: javafx

I have a problem to draw this image (below link) I had his in the middle of flow pane but only half of this! How to draw full image>?

http://s16.postimg.org/lrus832dx/Capture2.png

http://s27.postimg.org/hsujjp1s3/Capture1.png

Comment: Example code? Or should we consult an oracle?

Comment: Example of code if possible!

Comment: http://txt.do/6o5h or http://textuploader.com/6o5h!
 My code

Comment: Please put your code into your original question (edit it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand your problem now. I suggest you to use a `GridPane` instead, then you can do it this way:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    int rows = 2;
    int columns = 2;
    int rectangleWidth = 50;
    int rectangleHeight = 50;

    root.setMaxSize(rectangleWidth*columns, rectangleHeight*rows);

    for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for(int col= 0; col< columns; col++)
        {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(rectangleWidth, rectangleHeight);
            root.add(rectangle, col, row);

            if(row % 2 == 0)
            {
                rectangle.setFill(col % 2 == 0 ? Color.ORANGE : Color.BLACK);
            }
            else
            {
                rectangle.setFill(col % 2 != 0 ? Color.ORANGE : Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(root), 700, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

We need to wrap the `GridPane` containing the `Rectangle`s in a `StackPane` to center it in its parent.

Comment: @ie2020 if that answers your question please mark this answer accordingly.